# ShowDialog did not pop out

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

i have created global method that call showDialog, whenever i call it, it wont come out if i put Navigator.pop(context) , if i remove the navigator it will come out. I cannot close the errordialog if i dont have the navigator. Did i do something wrong? below is my code

```
class GlobalMethod {
  static void showErrorDialog(
      {required String error, required BuildContext ctx}) {
    showDialog(
        context: ctx,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Row(children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.logout,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  size: 35,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('Error Occured'),
              ),
            ]),
            content: Text(error,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.canPop(context) ? Navigator.canPop(context) : null;
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Okay',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }
```

This is example when i call the method. If i remove the Navigator.pop the error dialog will pop out, if i put the navigator.pop nothing will come out

```
else if (balance < price! ){
      GlobalMethod.showErrorDialog(error: "you dont have enough balance , please top up first", ctx: context);
      Navigator.pop(context);
      
    }
```

Comment: Remove Navigator.pop(context); after the dialog

Comment: Why are you using pop after showing you dialog? did you put there because you want to close your page after came back from dialog?

Comment: @SparkoSol if i remove the Navigator.pop , i cant close the error dialog

Comment: @eamirho3ein i want to close the error dialog

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove Navigator after the showErrorDialog:

```
else if (balance < price! ){
      GlobalMethod.showErrorDialog(error: "you dont have enough balance , please top up first", ctx: context);
      
}
```

then change this in your `showErrorDialog`:

```
onPressed: () {
    Navigator.canPop(context) ? Navigator.pop(context): null;
},
```

you are use `canPop` but you need to use `pop` for navigation, `canPop` just return you a bool result.

Comment: @Hisywm was it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

For the pop use Navigator.pop(context)

```
class GlobalMethod {
      static void showErrorDialog(
          {required String error, required BuildContext ctx}) {
        showDialog(
            context: ctx,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Row(children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.logout,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      size: 35,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text('Error Occured'),
                  ),
                ]),
                content: Text(error,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.canPop(ctx) ? Navigator.pop(context) : null;
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Okay',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            });
      }
    }
```

Remove pop

```
else if (balance < price! ){
      GlobalMethod.showErrorDialog(error: "you dont have enough balance , please top up first", ctx: context);
      
    }
```